# Python's list comprehension vs .NET LINQ

Tags: c#, python, linq, list-comprehension

The following simple LINQ code

```
string[] words = { "hello", "wonderful", "linq", "beautiful", "world" };

// Get only short words
var shortWords =
  from word in words
  where word.Length <= 5
  select word;

// Print each word out
shortWords.Dump();
```

can be translated into python using list comprehension as follows.

```
words = ["hello", "wonderful", "linq", "beautiful", "world"]
shortWords = [x for x in words if len(x) <=5]
print shortWords
```

- Is LINQ just another idea to implement list comprehension?
- What examples might be that LINQ can do but list comprehension can't do.

Comment: If you are lazy in C# consider writing this instead : words.Where(w => w.Length < 5).Dump();

Comment: As explained in [this epic explanation of monads](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhuHCtR3xq8), LINQ is carefully designed to be monadic, so it can be built on in simple, safe and effective ways.  Monads and functional programming are increasing rapidly in importance.  So I suggest folks address that in their answers.

Comment: @nealmcb A monad's only important in a language that doesn't support shared mutable state, just like static methods are only useful in languages that don't support first-class functions. It's a way to enforce ideological purity to allow a programming paradigm to do something it isn't well suited for just to be complete. As such, a monad's never going to increase in importance; it's a crutch to get around a self-imposed limitation. Generics vs. dynamic typing would be another example.

Comment: @alcalde - Static methods are perfectly useful in languages that do support first order functions. I have no idea how you came to your conclusion.

Comment: @Davor A class without data is illogical; an object is data and the methods that act on them. Static methods are only serving as a "loophole" to allow standalone functions in languages whose ideological purity forbids such things. If I can define a first-class function anywhere I have no need of sticking it in a class; I can code anything done with static methods without them with no loss of expressiveness or brevity. They're useless in such situations/languages.

Comment: @alcalde - and when you have a first class function that is needed only in one class, you don't see how it makes sense to make it private static for that class and limit its visibility that way?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

(Warning: Mammoth answer ahead. The part up to the first horizontal line makes a good tl;dr section, I suppose)

I'm not sure if I qualify as Python guru... but I have a solid grasp on iteration in Python, so let's try :)

First off: Afaik, LINQ queries are executed lazily - if that's the case, generator expressions are a closer Python concept (either way, list-, dict- and set comprehensions are conceptually just generator expressions fed to the list/dict/set constructor!).

Also, there is a conceptual difference: LINQ is for, as the name says, querying data structures. List-/dict-/set comprehensions are possible application of this (e.g. filtering and projecting the items of a list). So they are in fact less general (as we will see, many things built into LINQ are not built into them). Likewise, generator expressions are a way to formulate an one-time forward iterator in-place (I like to think of it as lambda for generator functions, only without an ugly, long keyword ;) ) and not a way to describe a complex query. They overlap, yes, but they are not identical. If you want all the power of LINQ in Python, you will have to write a fully-fledged generator. Or combine the numerous powerful generators built-in and in `itertools`.

---

Now, Python counterparts for the LINQ capabilities Jon Skeet named:

Projections: `(x.foo for ...)`

Filtering: `(... if x.bar > 5)`

> - Joins (x join y on x.foo equals y.bar)

The closest thing would be`((x_item, next(y_item for y_item in y if x_item.foo == y_item.bar)) for  x_item in x)`, I suppose.

Note that this will not iterate over the whole y for each x_item, it will only get the first match.

> - Group joins (x join y on x.foo equals y.bar into g)

This is harder. Python doesn't have anonymous types, though they are trivial to do yourself if you don't mind messing with `__dict__`:

```
class Anonymous(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__ = kwargs
```

Then, we could do `(Anonymous(x=x, y=y) for ...)` to get a list of objects that are have `x` and `y` members with the respective values.
The right thing is usually feeding the results to the constructor of an approriate class, say, XY.

> - Grouping (group x.foo by x.bar)

Now it gets hairy... there is no build-in way, afaik. But we can define it ourself if we need it:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def group_by(iterable, group_func):
    groups = defaultdict(list)
    for item in iterable:
        groups[group_func(item)].append(item)
    return groups
```

Example:

```
>>> from operator import attrgetter
>>> group_by((x.foo for x in ...), attrgetter('bar'))
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {some_value_of_bar: [x.foo of all x where x.bar == some_value_of_bar], some_other_value_of_bar: [...], ...})
```

This requires whatever we group by to be hashable, though. It's possible to avoid this, and I'll make a stab if there is public demand. But for now, I'm being lazy :)

We can also just return an iterable of groups without the values we grouped by, by calling `.values()` on the result (of course we can feed *that* to `list` to get something we can index and iterate several times). But who knows if we won't need the group values...

> - Ordering (orderby x.foo ascending, y.bar descending)

Sorting needs special syntax? The build-in `sorted` works for iterables, too: `sorted(x % 2 for x in range(10))` or `sorted(x for x in xs, key=attrgetter('foo'))`. Sorted ascending by default, the keyword argument `reverse` gives descending order.

Alas, afaik sorting by multiple attributes is not that easy, especially when mixing ascending and descending. Hmm... topic for a recipe?

> - Intermediate variables (let tmp = x.foo)

No, not possible in comprehensions or generator expressions - they are, as the name says, supposed to be expressions (and usually only span one or two lines). It's perfectly possible in generator function, though:

```
(x * 2 for x in iterable)
```

rewritten as generator with intermediate variable:

```
def doubles(iterable):
    for x in iterable:
        times2 = x * 2
        yield times2
```

Flattening: `(c for s in ("aa","bb") for c in s )`

---

> Note that although LINQ to Objects deals with delegates, other query providers (e.g. LINQ to SQL) can deal in expression trees  which describe the query instead of just presenting executable delegates. This allows the query to be translated into SQL (or other query languages) - again, I don't know whether Python supports that sort of thing or not. It's a significant part of LINQ though.

Python definitely does no such thing. List expressions correspond one-to-one to accumulating a plain list in a (possibly nested) for-loop, generator expressions correspond one-to-one to a generator.
Given the `parser` and `ast` module, it would be possible *in theory* to write a library for converting a comprehension into e.g. an SQL query. But nobody cares to.

Comment: To make some of this more "Pythonic" (i.e. native/idiomatic), check out Python's `collections.namedtuple` and `itertools.groupby`

Comment: Also for flattening: `itertools.chain`

Answer (score 25):

Well, you need to distinguish between some different things:

- LINQ standard query operators
- LINQ query expressions in C#
- LINQ query expressions in VB

C# doesn't support as much in query expressions as VB does, but here's what it *does* support:

- Projections (`select x.foo`)
- Filtering (`where x.bar > 5`)
- Joins (`x join y on x.foo equals y.bar`)
- Group joins (`x join y on x.foo equals y.bar into g`)
- Grouping (`group x.foo by x.bar`)
- Ordering (`orderby x.foo ascending, y.bar descending`)
- Intermediate variables (`let tmp = x.foo`)
- Flattening (`from x in y from z in x`)

I don't know how many of those are supported directly in Python's list comprehensions.

Note that although LINQ to Objects deals with delegates, other query providers (e.g. LINQ to SQL) can deal in *expression trees* which describe the query instead of just presenting executable delegates. This allows the query to be translated into SQL (or other query languages) - again, I don't know whether Python supports that sort of thing or not. It's a significant part of LINQ though.

Comment: "Anything you can do, I can do better..." See pynq (https://github.com/heynemann/pynq/wiki). Why not compare oranges to oranges? Anyway, list comprehensions aren't comparable to LINQ because they serve a completely different purpose. Where LINQ emphasizes expressiveness over performance, list comprehensions emphasize performance over expressiveness. They work similar to how you'd override a .Equals() method in C# via passing in a IEqualsComparator, except you're passing a generator function into the constructor of an iterator (ex list). I'm no guru but this is pretty basic stuff in python.

Comment: @EvanPlaice list comprehensions are not generators, the difference is using brackets vs parenthesis see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension, while in .Net Linq is always in memory and can be generated with the yield keyword (similar to generators but without the single use restriction)

Answer (score 17):

By using the [asq](http://asq.googlecode.com/) Python package you can easily do most things in Python that you can do in C# using LINQ-for-objects.  Using asq, your Python example becomes:

```
from asq.initiators import query
words = ["hello", "wonderful", "linq", "beautiful", "world"]
shortWords = query(words).where(lambda x: len(x) <= 5)
```

Answer (score 4):

I am no Python guru, but I would say that Python actually supports all of them as you can nest list comprehensions and include all the lambda expressions that you want. (list comprehensions tend to be hard to read if they get too complex, though...), but no it includes no "specific syntax" to accomplish all that.

Most of the functionality can be reproduced using :
 - **list comprehensions** or **generators**
 - lambda-functions or builtin functions (like `filter()` or `map()`) or functions from the `itertools` module

For instance, if you want to copy the behaviour of :

- **Projections** : that would be the left part of a list-comprehension ... which can be single values but also tuples. ex : `[ (k,v) for k,v in my_dict.items() if k.startswith("abc"]`. You may also use `map()`
- **Filtering** : that would be the expression on the right, after the `if`. You may also use `filter()`
- **Ordering** : just use the built-in `sorted()`
- **Grouping** or **aggregates** : use the builtin `min()`, `max()` or `itertools.groupby()`

Regarding **joins** or **flattening**, I think you would have to "to do it by hand"...

(Always good to have the [Python Quick Reference](http://rgruet.free.fr/PQR26/PQR2.6.html) at reach )