# Python's equivalent of C# LINQ's select

Tags: python

I'm quite new to python, and happen to have used C# for some time now. I saw that there was a filter method to use with the collections, which seems to be the equivalent of the LINQ's where clause.
I wondered, is there also an equivalent for the LINQ's select statement in python? 
Example: `my_collection.select(my_object => my_object.my_property)` would return a collection of the my_property of each object in my_collection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python's list comprehension vs .NET LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925093/pythons-list-comprehension-vs-net-linq)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [map()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map), but [List Comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) are a more "pythonic" way of doing this.

Answer (score 43):

```
[my_object.my_property for my_object in my_collection]
```

Comment: Just want to mention, for anybody finding this, the square brackets are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

try pandas!
select
C# `my_collection.Select(my_object => my_object.my_property)`
pandas `my_collection['my_property']`
or:
C# `my_collection.Select(x => x.my_property + 2)`
python `my_collection['my_property'].apply(lambda x: x + 2)`
where
C#: `my_collection.Where(x => x.my_property == 1)`
pandas: `my_collection[my_collection['my_property']==1]`