# Python LINQ like methods

Tags: python, linq, collections, list-comprehension

As new to Python i really miss LINQ methods. 
I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085337/linq-in-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925093/pythons-list-comprehension-vs-net-linq) questions, which helped me a lot to understand how Python enumerables and generators work.

But sill, I want to use good old methods like Select, SelectMany, First, Last, Group, Distinct and so on.

I understand, that all cases can be handled by generator and/or for expressions, but it decreases readability of code.

Comment: And I *hate* method chaining like those... I don't think many python programmers like that style. By the way: many of those functions can be found or implemented easily using the functions in [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html). see `groupby` for example.

Comment: Also see [this](http://sayspy.blogspot.com.au/2006/02/why-python-doesnt-need-something-like.html) link where it's explained how LINQ can be implemented only using generator expression plus the built-in `sorted` and `itertools.groupby`.

Comment: @Bakuriu yes, I saw that article, it is mentioned as answer in one of linked questions. Still, it is much simple for me personally to have set of methods like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eventually I've mock almost all Linq methods and made a proper wrapper, so you can **chain** methods.

**It supports**

any, all, first, first_or_none, last, last_or_none, to_list, to_dictionary, where, distinct, group_by, order_by, take, skip, select, select_many, foreach, concat, concat_item, except_for, intersect

**Usage examples**

```
# Chaining: ['#1', '#2', '#3']
print Linq([-1, 0, 1, 2, 3])\
        .where(lambda i: i > 0)\
        .select(lambda i: "#" + repr(i))

# Getting single item: 2
print Linq([1, 2, 3, 4]).first(lambda i: i > 1)

# Grouping by: {'even': [2], 'odd': [1, 3]}
print Linq([1, 2, 3])\
        .group_by(lambda i: "even" if i % 2 == 0 else "odd")

# I always loved this function: {1: 'This is number 1', 2: 'This is number 2', 3: 'This is number 3'}
print Linq([1, 2, 3])\
        .to_dictionary(lambda i: i, lambda i: "This is number " + repr(i))
```

**Source code**

```
"""
LINQ analog for Python
Contact: purin.anton@gmail.com
"""
__author__ = 'Anton Purin'
import itertools


class Linq(object):
    """Allows to apply LINQ-like methods to wrapped iterable"""

    class LinqException(Exception):
        """
        Special exception to be thrown by Linq
        """
        pass

    def __init__(self, iterable):
        """
        Instantiates Linq wrapper
        :param iterable: iterable to wrap
        """
        if iterable is None:
            raise Linq.LinqException("iterable is None")
        if iterable.__class__ is Linq:
            self.iterable = iterable.iterable
        else:
            self.iterable = iterable

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.to_list())

    def __iter__(self):
        """
        Allows to iterate Linq object
        """
        return iter(self.iterable)

    def any(self, predicate=None):
        """
        Returns true if there any item which matches given predicate.
        If no predicate given returns True if there is any item at all.
        :param predicate: Function which takes item as argument and returns bool
        :returns: Boolean
        :rtype: bool
        """
        for i in self.iterable:
            if predicate is None:
                return True
            elif predicate(i):
                return True
        return False

    def all(self, predicate):
        """
        Returns true if all items match given predicate.
        :param predicate: Function which takes item as argument and returns bool
        :returns: Boolean
        :rtype: bool
        """
        for i in self.iterable:
            if not predicate(i):
                return False
        return True

    def first(self, predicate=None):
        """
        Returns first item which matches predicate or first item if no predicate given.
        Raises exception, if no matching items found.
        :param predicate: Function which takes item as argument and returns bool
        :returns: item
        :rtype: object
        """
        for i in self.iterable:
            if predicate is None:
                return i
            elif predicate(i):
                return i
        raise Linq.LinqException('No matching items!')

    def first_or_none(self, predicate=None):
        """
        Returns first item which matches predicate or first item if no predicate given.
        Returns None, if no matching items found.
        :param predicate: Function which takes item as argument and returns bool
        :returns: item
        :rtype: object
        """
        try:
            return self.first(predicate)
        except Linq.LinqException:
            return None

    def last(self, predicate=None):
        """
        Returns last item which matches predicate or last item if no predicate given.
        Raises exception, if no matching items found.
        :param predicate: Function which takes item as argument and returns bool
        :returns: item
        :rtype: object
        """
        last_item = None
        last_item_set = False
        for i in self.iterable:
            if (predicate is not None and predicate(i)) or (predicate is None):
                last_item = i
                last_item_set = True

        if not last_item_set:
            raise Linq.LinqException('No matching items!')
        return last_item

    def last_or_none(self, predicate=None):
        """
        Returns last item which matches predicate or last item if no predicate given.
        Returns None, if no matching items found.
        :param predicate: Function which takes item as argument and returns bool
        :returns: item
        :rtype: object
        """
        try:
            return self.last(predicate)
        except Linq.LinqException:
            return None

    def to_list(self):
        """
        Converts LinqIterable to list
        :returns: list
        :rtype: list
        """
        return list(self.iterable)

    def to_dictionary(self, key_selector=None, value_selector=None, unique=True):
        """
        Converts LinqIterable to dictionary
        :param key_selector: function which takes item and returns key for it
        :param value_selector: function which takes item and returns value for it
        :param unique: boolean, if True that will throw exception if keys are not unique
        :returns: dict
        :rtype: dict
        """
        result = {}
        keys = set() if unique else None

        for i in self.iterable:
            key = key_selector(i) if key_selector is not None else i
            value = value_selector(i) if value_selector is not None else i
            if unique:
                if key in keys:
                    raise Linq.LinqException("Key '" + repr(key) + "' is used more than once.")
                keys.add(key)
            result[key] = value
        return result

    def where(self, predicate):
        """
        Returns items which matching predicate function
        :param predicate: Function which takes item as argument and returns bool
        :returns: results wrapped with Linq
        :rtype: Linq
        """
        return Linq([i for i in self.iterable if predicate(i)])

    def distinct(self, key_selector=None):
        """
        Filters distinct values from enumerable
        :param key_selector: function which takes item and returns key for it
        :returns: results wrapped with Linq
        :rtype: Linq
        """
        key_selector = key_selector if key_selector is not None else lambda item: item
        keys = set()
        return Linq([i for i in self.iterable if key_selector(i) not in keys and not keys.add(key_selector(i))])

    def group_by(self, key_selector=None, value_selector=None):
        """
        Groups given items by keys.
        :param key_selector: function which takes item and returns key for it
        :param value_selector: function which takes item and returns value for it
        :returns: Dictionary, where value if Linq for given key
        :rtype: dict
        """
        key_selector = key_selector if key_selector is not None else lambda item: item
        value_selector = value_selector if value_selector is not None else lambda item: item

        result = {}
        for i in self.iterable:
            key = key_selector(i)
            if result.__contains__(key):
                result[key].append(value_selector(i))
            else:
                result[key] = [value_selector(i)]
        for key in result:
            result[key] = Linq(result[key])
        return result

    def order_by(self, value_selector=None, comparer=None, descending=False):
        """
        Orders items.
        :param value_selector: function which takes item and returns value for it
        :param comparer: function which takes to items and compare them returning int
        :param descending: shows how items will be sorted
        """
        return Linq(sorted(self.iterable, comparer, value_selector, descending))

    def take(self, number):
        """
        Takes only given number of items, of all available items if their count is less than number
        :param number: number of items to get
        :returns: results wrapped with Linq
        :rtype: Linq
        """
        def internal_take(iterable, number):
            count = 0
            for i in iterable:
                count += 1
                if count > number:
                    break
                yield i

        return Linq(internal_take(self.iterable, number))

    def skip(self, number):
        """
        Skips given number of items in enumerable
        :param number: number of items to get
        :returns: results wrapped with Linq
        :rtype: Linq
        """
        def internal_skip(iterable, number):
            count = 0
            for i in iterable:
                count += 1
                if count <= number:
                    continue
                yield i

        return Linq(internal_skip(self.iterable, number))

    def select(self, selector):
        """
        Converts items in list with given function
        :param selector: Function which takes item and returns other item
        :returns: results wrapped with Linq
        :rtype: Linq
        """
        return Linq([selector(i) for i in self.iterable])

    def select_many(self, selector):
        """
        Converts items in list with given function
        :param selector: Function which takes item and returns iterable
        :returns: results wrapped with Linq
        :rtype: Linq
        """
        return Linq([i for i in [selector(sub) for sub in self.iterable]])

    def foreach(self, func):
        """
        Allows to perform some action for each object in iterable, but not allows to redefine items
        :param func: Function which takes item as argument
        :returns: self
        :rtype: Linq
        """
        for i in self.iterable:
            func(i)
        return self

    def concat(self, iterable):
        """
        Concats two iterables
        :param iterable: Any iterable
        :returns: self
        :rtype: Linq
        """
        return Linq(itertools.chain(self.iterable, iterable))

    def concat_item(self, item):
        """
        Concats iterable with single item
        :param item: Any item
        :returns: self
        :rtype: Linq
        """
        return Linq(itertools.chain(self.iterable, [item]))

    def except_for(self, iterable):
        """
        Filters items except given iterable
        :param iterable: Any iterable
        :returns: self
        :rtype: Linq
        """
        return Linq([i for i in self.iterable if i not in iterable])

    def intersect(self, iterable):
        """
        Intersection between two iterables
        :param iterable: Any iterable
        :returns: self
        :rtype: Linq
        """
        return Linq([i for i in self.iterable if i in iterable])
```

As you can see, some of this cases are easily handled by python, while some of them are not. Take a piece of .NET to Python.

Comment: ```lambda i: "#" + `i` ``` Please don't use the ` (backtick). It's been deprecated for a decade or so (together with `<>`) and it's gone in python3. Just call `repr`.

Answer (score 10):

Give a try to [py-linq](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-linq)!

### Installation

```
pip install py_linq
```

### Usage

```
from py_linq import Enumerable

x = Enumerable([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
x.first() # 1
x.skip(1)\
  .where(lambda i: i < 5)\
  .to_list() # [2, 3, 4]
```